# How to display different data points on GMAP given a criteria on Bokeh python

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am trying to utilize gmaps with bokeh to display a visualization of all houses in my dataframe in the NYC area. I have it to display all the houses but the issue I am having is how do I setup a slider to control which datapoints are being display on my plot given a range of values for example I would like my slider to only show houses priced between 250,000-500,000 and etc. This is my code.

```
bokeh.io.reset_output()
output_notebook()
API_KEY = 'Key....'
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=40.750042, lng=-73.906670, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

source = ColumnDataSource(
 data=nyc_df
)

p = gmap('Key', map_options, title="New York City")
tooltips = [("price","@price"), ("Address","@StreetAddress"), ("Neighborhood", 
"@Neighborhood")]
p.circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=3, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, 
source=source)
p.add_tools( HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))

js_code = """
        var data = source.data
        var f = slider.value
        var price = data['price']
        var x = data['latitude']
        var y = data['longitude']
        for (var i = 0; i<price.length; i++){
            if (price[i] <= f && price[i] > (f-250000)) {
                p.circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=3, fill_color="blue", 
                fill_alpha=0.8, source=data[i])
            }
            else {
            continue
            }
        }
        source.change.emit()
"""


slider = Slider(title="Price: ", start=min(nyc_df.price), 
                       end=max(nyc_df.price), value=100000, step=250000)

update_js = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, slider=slider), code=js_code)
slider.js_on_change('value', update_js)


show(column(slider, p))
```

My thought process basically to reset the map dots each time the value changes but I know this is wrong and if there is a different method without replotting the data points perphaps some of the points just disappears given the range of values would be more effective.

I have tried googling but it seems I can't seem to find anything similar to my problem. I am still fairly new to this I apogolize for my poor code ahead of time. Here is the result.

[gmap of nyc houses for sale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbk4h.png)